# Undefined reference with link time optimization and --as-needed ld flag

Tags: c++, linker, g++, ld, link-time-optimization

I'm having some troubles compiling a large C++ project that uses link time optimization. After some digging I managed to produce an (almost) minimal working example that exhibits the same issue.

Say that I have the following **foo.cpp** file:

```
//foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    //bar(); //Everything works if this is uncommented

    return 0;
}
```

Where **bar.h** and **bar.cpp** look like this:

```
//bar.h
#ifndef __BAR_H__
#define __BAR_H__

void bar();

#endif
```

and

```
//bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include <thread>

void bar()
{
    std::thread t([] {});
    t.join();
}
```

The code is compiled like this:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -flto -c foo.cpp
$ g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -flto -c bar.cpp
```

But trying to link the object files results in a undefined reference error:

```
$ g++ -flto -Wl,-as-needed foo.o bar.o -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody please explain what is going on here?

Some notes:

- Adding the -pthread flag makes no difference.
- I'm explicitly passing the option -Wl,-as-needed as, on my system, this is not the default. However, this is the default behavior in some other GNU/Linux distributions.
- Linking succeeds if I uncomment the call to bar() in foo.cpp.
- Linking succeeds if the option -Wl,--as-needed is removed (or -Wl,--no-as-needed is added).
- I'm using g++ 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) but the same problem appears in g++ 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04).

Edit: clang with lld works fine.

```
$ clang++ -fuse-ld=lld -flto -Wl,-as-needed foo.o bar.o -lpthread
$ ./a.out 
Hello world
```

Comment: Seems like a linker bug to me, maybe file a bug report

Comment: Linking with -pthread does not make any difference. Also compiling with -pthread does not make any difference, regardless on whether -pthread is used for linking or not.

Comment: If the gold linker is installed, try linking with `-fuse-ld=gold`. But as M.M said, this looks like a linker bug. It's probably worth reporting. I use the latest version of binutils (2.32) and I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NikosC. Everything works with gold. Thank you for confirming the issue. I'll look into filing a bug report.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed in binutils 2.32.51.20190707-1 in Debian testing.

Comment: @Steven, thank you for this question, all my questions were marked as a duplicate (which they werent) and now after another 3h I finally found this, you are my hero ^^